# Spring @ModelAttribute Model field mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am rewriting an old REST service written in an in-house framework to use Spring. I have a Controller with a POST method which takes a parameter either as a POST or as `x-www-form-urlencoded` body. Following multiple StackOverflow answers, I used @ModelAttribute annotation and created a model.

My problem is that the old REST API is using a property name in snake case - say `some_property`. I want my Java code to follow the Java naming conventions so in my model the field is called `someProperty`. I tried using the @JsonProperty annotation as I do in my DTO objects but this time this didn't work. I only managed to make the code work if the field in the model was named `some_property`. Here is my example code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my/api/root")
public class SomethingController {

    @PostMapping("/my/api/suffix")
    public Mono<Object> getSomething(
            @RequestParam(name = "some_property", required = false) String someProperty,
            @ModelAttribute("some_property") Model somePropertyModel) {
        // calling my service here
    }

    public class Model {
        @JsonProperty("some_property")
        private String someProperty;

        private String some_property;
        // Getters and setters here
    }
}
```

I am searching for annotation or any other elegant way to keep the Java naming style in the code but use the legacy property name from the REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@JsonProperty` annotation can only work with the JSON format, but you're using `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you can't change your POST type, you have to write your own Jackson ObjectMapper:

[@JsonProperty not working for Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757946/jsonproperty-not-working-for-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it led me to the answer to my question - no there is no elegant way to achieve what I want. I am not going to write a ton of code for aesthetic purposes.
As of now, there is no suitable annotation (see the Spring Jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13433).
One of the answers to the question you linked (not the accepted one) let to an article which shows several alternative approaches to solving this problem. Here is the link: https://afitnerd.com/2017/05/24/what-if-spring-boot-handled-forms-like-json/

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel Alright, thanks for you feedback, TIL.

Answer (score -1):

I also met a similar case you,
Please replace `@ModelAttribute("some_property")` with `@RequestBody`.

Hope to help you!